# Selecting only one element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a table with a number of items. I'm trying to show input fields when a user clicks on an edit button, but I don't know how to select only the element within the same row as the edit button. Here's the table structure:

```
<table>

    <tr class="table-row">
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="item-name">Item 1</a>
          <input type="text" value="[item]" class="input-item" id="item-1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="item-name">Price 1</a>
          <input type="text" value="[item]" class="input-item" id="price-1">
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="edit-button">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="table-row">
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="item-name">Item 2</a>
          <input type="text" value="[item]" class="input-item" id="item-2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="item-name">Price 2</a>
          <input type="text" value="[item]" class="input-item" id="price-2">
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="edit-button">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>

    ...

</table>
```

What I intend to happen, is that when the user clicks on the `Edit` link within a specific row, the input fields will appear (in the 1st and 2nd columns) and the text will disappear, allowing the user to edit from the table itself. Problem is, the jQuery code I have (obviously) selects all the `.input-item` classes, thus showing all the inputs from all the rows.

```
$('.edit-button').click(function(event){
  $('.input-item').show();
});
```

How do I use jQuery to select only the inputs within the `.table-row` of the clicked `Edit` link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need traverse up to `.table-row` using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method in current element context i.e. `this`, then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target descendant `.input-item` elements.

```
$('.edit-button').click(function(event){
  $(this).closest('.table-row').find('.input-item').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
  $(this).closest('tr.table-row').find('.input-item').show();
```

Comment: I was about to write the same thing, would be nice if you hide the texts too (as mentioned in the question) and write complete code (include .click function(){...} to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Comment: [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) will not work as it traverses to the immediate parent

Comment: `parent` would work without a selector, but since here we are not looking for immediate parent, you should change it to `parents`

Comment: Nope, immediate parent is `td`, we wanna look into `tr`

Comment: Use `closest` instead of `parent` and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector (i used toggle instead of show only for demo):

```js
$(function () {
  $('.edit-button').click(function (event) {
    $(this).parent().siblings(':has(".input-item")').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table>

    <tr class="table-row">
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="item-name">Item 1</a>
            <input type="text" value="[item]" class="input-item" id="item-1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="item-name">Price 1</a>
            <input type="text" value="[item]" class="input-item" id="price-1">
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="edit-button">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="table-row">
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="item-name">Item 2</a>
            <input type="text" value="[item]" class="input-item" id="item-2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="item-name">Price 2</a>
            <input type="text" value="[item]" class="input-item" id="price-2">
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="edit-button">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```